# jQuery .each function help

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I was wondering what I was doing wrong here. The first function runs just fine when the reset button is called, but for some reason the second function isn't doing anything. The form does get reset but the second alert never pops up and the warn class is never removed. Thanks for your help!

```
$('#registration :reset').click(function() {
    alert("reset was clicked");
    $('#registration :text').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasclass('warn')) {
            $(this).removeClass('warn');
        }

        if (!$(this).hasclass('texta')) {
            $(this).addClass('texta');
        }

        alert("value");
    });
});
```

Comment: This probably won't solve the problem, but you can shorten that to `$('#registration :text').removeClass('warn').addClass('texta');`.

Comment: you're saying the overall code works just the first time, or the .each() method never works?

Comment: Since it actually *might* solve the problem, I added this as an answer... :)

Comment: sidenote : use FireBug in Firefox (or FireBug Lite in Chrome) for js errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javascript language is [case-sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity). The `hasclass()` method does not exist, but [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) does. You should write:

```
$('#registration :text').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('warn')) {
        $(this).removeClass('warn');
    }

    if (!$(this).hasClass('texta')) {
        $(this).addClass('texta');
    }

    alert("value");
});
```

That said, you usually don't need to call `hasClass()` before [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), because `addClass()` won't add a duplicate if the element already has the class you specify, and `removeClass()` won't remove a class the element doesn't have. So you can simply write:

```
$('#registration :text').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('warn');
    $(this).addClass('texta');
    alert("value");
});
```

Or, using method chaining like @deceze does:

```
$('#registration :text').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('warn').addClass('texta');
    alert("value");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
$('#registration :text').removeClass('warn').addClass('texta');
```

---

Behold ze Magik of jQuery!

Pretty much every jQuery method works on **every element returned by the `$` function**. So there's no need to loop through all results, `removeClass` and `addClass` will be applied to all elements found by the `#registration :text` selector. Furthermore, there's no need to do any checking before removing or adding classes. If you're adding the class and the element already has the class, nothing happens. Vice versa for removing a class.

Try reading [a tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me%3a_Using_selectors_and_events), this is what makes jQuery so powerful!

Comment: accidentally answered the question :)

Comment: Will you please explain how this works? I love how simple it is, I just want to know.

Comment: @samuel this is called jquery chaining, which is good with performance also//

Comment: @Samuel Because you can't add the same class to an element which already has it, and similarly can't remove it when the element already has that class. That, and the fact that both functions will act on all elements matched by the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use live , as they are getting added and removed ,

i think when you remove they are getting un binded..

```
$('#registration :reset').live('click', function() {
    alert("reset was clicked");
    $('#registration :text').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('warn')) {
            $(this).removeClass('warn');
        }

        if (!$(this).hasClass('texta')) {
            $(this).addClass('texta');
        }

        alert("value");
    });
});
```